# How to use checkboxes in a datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

You can view below image!...
How to do it?

[image]

Comment: Controls can contain controls in windows forms. I guess that's how you do it. Look into WPF projects. There's a pretty decent tutorial on it that explains how to make such controls.

Comment: Do you have any idea in windows form application?

Comment: See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, but it's rather trivial to understand and rather difficult to explain, so I'd urge you to just download visual studio and create a new windows forms project. There you'll have the option to create your own form using the built in windows form designer.

Comment: i have VS 2015, Do you know how to take text with checkbox ! I mean you just watch it and gimme some coding knowledge!

Comment: how to take text with checkboxes in a datagridview!

Comment: Step1: Drag checkbox to your control
Step2: Drag label next to your checkbox in your control
Step3: ???
Step4: Profit

Comment: can we drag and drop the commands in a datagridview???

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur, if you want some code, then show us your code how your `DataGridView` filled with data. You can use two columns `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and `DataGridViewTextboxColumn`. Put them side by side

Comment: Why did you remove the image? It provides a valuable explanation of what you are attempting to do. If you wish to remove it, you should at least provide a good text explanation of what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use template for row(checkbox+text) with binding for text and checkbox check state